# $a$ is a torsion element of the group $G$, $yay^{-1}=a^k \neq a$. Can we conclude that $\langle a,y\rangle $ is a finite group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Assume that $G$ is a group. Also, $a$ is a  torsion element of $G$ such that $a^m=1$, for some natural number $m$. Also, there exists an element $y \in G $ such that $yay^{-1}=a^k \neq a$, when $gcd(k,m)=1$ and $1<k<m$. Can we conclude that $\langle a,y\rangle $ is a finite group?

Notice that $\langle a\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $\langle a,y\rangle$. In addition, $\langle a,y\rangle/\langle a\rangle \cong \langle y\rangle/(\langle a\rangle \cap  \langle y\rangle )$. Also, we know that for any natural number $t$, $b^tab^{-t}=a^{k^t}$.  We have $gcd(k,m)=1$, so for some natural number $t$,   $b^tab^{-t}=a$.

Comment: $\langle a,y\rangle$ is finite if and only if $y$ is of finite order. Is this the condition you are looking for?

Comment: By this conditions, can we find an example that  the group  $G$ is infinite?

Comment: Yes, you can. For any $1 < k < m$ with $\text{gcd}(k, m) = 1$, you can consider the group with presentation $\langle a, y | a^m = 1, yay^{-1} = a^k \rangle$. You can alternatively describe this as the semidirect product $\mathbb Z/m \mathbb Z \rtimes \mathbb Z$, where $1 \in \mathbb Z$ acts by multiplication with $k$. Then let $a$ be a generator of $\mathbb Z/m \mathbb Z$ and let $y=1 \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: As @freakish pointed out, you need to also assume that $y$ is of finite order. Otherwise we can cook up examples like
$$
a=\pmatrix{e^{2\pi i/3}&0&0\cr0&e^{-2\pi i/3}&0\cr 0&0&1\cr}$$
and
$$y=\pmatrix{0&1&0\cr 1&0&0\cr 0&0&2\cr}.$$ Here $m=3$, $k=2$, but the bottom right entry of $y^\ell$ grows without bound.